# Vapour pressure deficit (VPD) calculation from ERA5 (Google Earth Engine)

Tags: google-earth-engine

Using Google Earth Engine, I want to estimate the Vapour pressure deficit (VPD) from ERA5.

I have found a document of VPD estimation and approximation via [this](https://andrewsforest.oregonstate.edu/sites/default/files/lter/data/studies/ms01/dewpt_vpd_calculations.pdf) but I wonder if it is appropriate to apply to GEE data.

I know that there is some ready-to-use ERA5-VPD dataset from other resources, but I want to calculate it myself using ERA5 from GEE for my personal use.

Does anyone have experience in this matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can estimate the Vapor Pressure Deficit (VPD) from ERA5 because this product has bands involved in relative humidity (Rh/100) calculation (one of intermediate parameters for obtaining VPD); as air temperature (Ta) and dew point temperature (Td). Following formula for relative humidity was derived from [document](https://andrewsforest.oregonstate.edu/sites/default/files/lter/data/studies/ms01/dewpt_vpd_calculations.pdf) in above link.

[image]

Following code uses above formula for estimating, at global scale, Rh/100 values for dates range between '2019-07-01' and '2019-07-31'.

```
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('ECMWF/ERA5/DAILY')
                   .select('mean_2m_air_temperature', 'dewpoint_2m_temperature')
                   .filter(ee.Filter.date('2019-07-01', '2019-07-31'));

var dataset = dataset.map(function (img) {
  
  var Rh_100 = img.expression(
    'exp((17.269 * Td)/(273.3 + Td) - (17.269 * Ta)/(237.3 + Ta))', 
    {'Td': img.select('dewpoint_2m_temperature'),
     'Ta': img.select('mean_2m_air_temperature')
    }
    ).rename('Rh_100');
  
  return img.addBands(Rh_100);
  
});

print(dataset);

// Visualization palette for Rh_100 
var visRh_100  = {"opacity":1,
                  "bands":["Rh_100"],
                  "min":0.2855575366354103,
                  "max":0.5430716815597737,
                  "palette":["efff0e","ffb202","ff2804","130eff"]};

Map.addLayer(
    dataset.filter(ee.Filter.date('2019-07-15'))
       .select('Rh_100'), visRh_100,
    'Rh_100');

Map.setCenter(21.2, 22.2, 2);
```

After running above code in GEE code editor, loaded layer is for '2019-07-15' day. It can be observed in following picture.

[image]

Now, you only have to calculate **es** (the saturation vapor pressure or vapor pressure at air temperature) by using following formula presents in your referred [document](https://andrewsforest.oregonstate.edu/sites/default/files/lter/data/studies/ms01/dewpt_vpd_calculations.pdf) for obtaining VPD.

> Vapor Pressure Deficit = es * (1 ‐ Rh/100) at any instant